# Use this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); to control android phone rocker when activity is out of focus (with service)?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, media, volume

I am working on a android music player app that also plays music in the background. I used this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); to change the media volume when the activity is in focus. But is there a way to control the media volume with rocker when my player is out of focus? (maybe by creating a service?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you want a Service.  I imagine that the Service could have listeners for the volume buttons, and it would also need listeners for broadcasts that your program would send it.

It would also send broadcasts to your app when it needs to communicate with it.  I have a fairly simple music streaming service, but there are eight broadcasts that can be sent between the two.  (Things like: "Turn off", "What is the play status", "Start", "Service has successfully started", "Service has unsuccessfully started", "Stop".)